# Inconsistent output from swashbuckle cli to generate swagger.json from local workstation vs build agent (azure devops) using script task

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm trying to generate the swagger.json as part of my build process using swashbucklecli and when i run the below command from command prompt on my local workstation the swagger.json file generates with right properties (example: serverUrl has the right value) but when run the same command as part of the build process in azure devops the serverUrl property is empty.

```
dotnet swagger tofile --output swagger.json myAPI\myAPI.dll v1
```

5.6.3 swashbuckle.aspnetcore.cli

3.1 Core SDK

Comment: Did you get any error message in Azure DevOps build? Which build agent pool did you use? Could you share your pipeline? Try to set variable `system.debug` to `True`, to see whether you could get more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I've noticed hosted agent is using SDK Version: 5.0.103, .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.
2. Check whether you ran the command from the same working directory on local machine and agent machine. Empty working directory in `DotNetCoreCLI` task is the root of the repo (build) or artifacts (release), which is `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`. You could try to specify `workingDirectory` in `DotNetCoreCLI` task.

Comment: Yes, i have the workingDirectory already set on the task. One thing i noticed about the SDK version is on my local i have multiple versions installed and the latest is 5.X however though build agents has 5.x i'm specifically installing 3.x prior to executing this because of the dependency with other task and not sure if this causing the inconsistency. I will research further. thanks for your input.